# JQuery find() не всё находит

Tags: jquery, xml, api

$(xml).find() находит все кроме URL картинки.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<anime>
  <entry>
    <id>2889</id>
    <title>Bleach - The DiamondDust Rebellion</title>
    <english>Bleach: Diamond Dust Rebellion</english>
    <synonyms>Bleach: The Diamond Dust Rebellion - M&Aring; Bleach - The DiamondDust Rebellion - Mou Hitotsu no Hyourinmaru</synonyms>
    <episodes>1</episodes>
    <type>Movie</type>
    <status>Finished Airing</status>
    <start_date>2007-12-22</start_date>
    <end_date>2007-12-22</end_date>
    <synopsis>Some synopsis</synopsis>
    <image>https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/6/4052.jpg</image>
  </entry>
</anime>
```

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', "https://myanimelist.net/api/anime/search.xml?q=" + query, false, LOGIN, PASSWORD);
req.send();
var animeXml = req.responseText;
$(animeXml).find("entry").each(function() {

  animeEntrys.push(new AnimeEntry($(this).find("id").text(), $(this).find("title").text(), $(this).find("english").text(), $(this).find("synonyms").text(),
    $(this).find("episodes").text(), $(this).find("type").text(), $(this).find("status").text(), $(this).find("start_date").text(), $(this).find("end_date").text(),
    $(this).find("synopsis").text(), $(this).find("image").text()));
  console.log("findImage: ".format($(this).find("image").text()));
  console.log("findImage: ".format($(this).find("image")));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: $(this).find("image").text() - возвращает пустую строку

Comment: А что возвращает $(this).find("image") ?

Comment: @Cheg http://i68.tinypic.com/2zq4w1e.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(animeXml)` парсит ответ сервера как HTML код, несмотря на его XML структуру. В HTML у тега `<image>` не может быть содержимого, поэтому ничего и не возвращается.

Для парсинга XML в jQuery есть `$.parseXML`, который вернёт XML дерево, которое снова можно скормить jQuery, и вот тогда-то код заработает:

```
var animeXml = req.responseText;
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(animeXml);
$(xmlDoc).find("entry").each(function() {
...
```

Однако, есть нюанс: с приведённым XML у меня браузер отказался что-либо делать, ссылаясь на неправильно сформированный XML - без указания места, где же он неправильный. Экспериментальным путём удалось определить, что виноват `&Aring;`, но почему и как этого избежать - непонятно.

Comment: $.parseXML(animeXml); теперь работает, спасибо! Я не совсем понял что за ошибка у Вас, дальше код у меня работает нормально.

Comment: @DanilKondratiev Хорошо, что работает :) Тогда просто будьте готовы к тому, что $.parseXML может выбросить Exception, если по каким-либо причинам XML придёт покорёженный.